# Javafx Alert makes program freeze

Tags: java, javafx, error-handling, alert, freeze

I created a mp3 program using JavaFx (.fxml) and model view controller architecture.

I want to create an alert when the user clicks the about this program that will tell them a little bit about the program.

The problem I have is that right now whenever the button is pressed the cursor starts spinning and I can't click any more buttons in the UI.

I have tried multiple snippets of code I found online but they all cause my program to freeze.

Here is my .fxml file and the function in the controller. Any idea why it is freezing?

```
<center>
<TitledPane fx:id="titledPane" animated="false" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Music">
  <BorderPane>
    <center>
      <ListView fx:id="songList" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    </center>
    <top>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" padding="$x1" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" spacing="15.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <children>
          <Label fx:id="DirLabel" text="" wrapText="true" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectDir" text="Browse..." />
          <Button onAction="#alert" text="About this Program" />
        </children>
      </HBox>
    </top>
  </BorderPane>
</TitledPane>
```

controller file

```
//about the program alert
    @FXML
    private void alert(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "thank you for using java");
    }
```

Comment: Define 'freezes'.  Does the mp3 stop playing or does the UI hang?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: My cursor starts spinning and it loads forever and I cant click any more buttons in the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix Swing components (like `JOptionPane`) with JavaFX unless you really have to. In the event that you do have to, you must manage swing components from the AWT event dispatch thread and JavaFX nodes from the FX Application Thread, which gets very tricky. The reason your application is hanging is that you are trying to show a swing window from the FX Application Thread, which (on some platforms) causes deadlock (two threads waiting for each other before they can proceed).

Instead, use an [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html):

```
@FXML
private void alert() {
    new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "thank you for using JavaFX").showAndWait();
}
```